# Is there a way to space bootstrap card grids and max out the limit?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So, basicly i have bootstrap cards in a for loop in flask. Everything works well, but when ever i pass 3 cards a new column starts and it gets really annoying.

Screenshot Example: https://ibb.co/jTvtSbq

Even the vertical spacing look pretty weird on the bottom.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
    <div class="col">
    <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'  style="width: 400px; border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white; bottom: -22pc; left: -18pc; ">
      <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white" >Teacher&#39;s Homework</h5>
      <div class="card-body" style="color: white" >
       <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
        <p class="card-text">No </p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
       </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="col">
    <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'  style="width: 400px; border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white; bottom: -22pc; left: -18pc; ">
      <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white" >SomeNewTask</h5>
      <div class="card-body" style="color: white" >
       <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Yes </p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
       </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="col">
    <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'  style="width: 400px; border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white; bottom: -22pc; left: -18pc; ">
      <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white" >wdaadadawdawdad</h5>
      <div class="card-body" style="color: white" >
       <h5 class="card-title">Test</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Yes </p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
       </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="col">
    <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'  style="width: 400px; border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white; bottom: -22pc; left: -18pc; ">
      <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white" >wdadwadadadwadawdad</h5>
      <div class="card-body" style="color: white" >
       <h5 class="card-title">Test</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Yes </p>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
       </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to make a parent `<div class="col">` in every card.
2. Remove card   `width: 400px; bottom: -22pc; left: -18pc;`

Full code below -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-cols-auto g-4">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">Teacher&#39;s Homework</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">No </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">SomeNewTask</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Yes </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">SomeNewTask</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Yes </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">SomeNewTask</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Yes </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">SomeNewTask</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Yes </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">Teacher&#39;s Homework</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">No </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">Teacher&#39;s Homework</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">No </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" id='cardPostPost'
                    style=" border-radius: 23px; background-color: rgb(35, 33, 33); color: white;">
                    <h5 class="card-header border-bottom border-light" style="color: white">Teacher&#39;s Homework</h5>
                    <div class="card-body" style="color: white">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Homework</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">No </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so i got problem 1 solved with your answer, but now for problem 2 how would i fix it without removing the card width and stuff.

Comment: You can use width. But when it exceeds the device width, it will breakdown into another row

Comment: Oh. Is there a way to fix that without changing the width?

Comment: Remove row-cols-auto

Comment: It looks like this now: https://ibb.co/r3c8DVF

Comment: My Code is here: https://justpaste.it/cicqf

Comment: remove bottom: -22pc; left: -18pc

Comment: Here is my code now: https://ibb.co/txYBbQC
And this is how it looks like: https://ibb.co/tmsNmX2